# Add Virtual Host in Apache Windows 10

Tags: windows, apache, ssl

I am trying to add Virtual Hosts with SSL certificates to Apache on a Windows 10 environment.

It is my first time using Apache (total newb!), and have done my basic setup using online tutorials and blogs. My Apache service is running, and I am able to get the correct response when typing localhost in the browser. **However**, when I add my new Virtual Host, and try to restart the Apache service, it fails (Error 1067: The process terminated unexpectedly).

The problem seems to be with my SSL certificates in the setup. When I delete the certificate lines in the code below, the Apache service restarts with no problem. However the new Virtual Host does not open/resolve. I think this is due to the required certificates(?).

Here is my code:

**In my httpd-vhosts.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerAdmin name@domain.co.za
        ServerName  odyssey.rain.network
        ServerAlias odyssey.rain.network

        DocumentRoot c:/Apache24/htdocs/odyssey.rain.network

        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile      c:/Apache24/ssl/network/server.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile   c:/Apache24/ssl/network/rain.key
        SSLCertificateChainFile c:/Apache24/ssl/network/ca.crt

        ErrorLog logs/odyssey.rain.network-error.log
        CustomLog logs/odyssey.rain.network-access.log combined

        <Directory c:/Apache24/htdocs/odyssey.rain.network>
                AllowOverride All
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin name@domain.co.za
        ServerName odyssey.rain.network
        Redirect / https://odyssey.rain.network
</VirtualHost>
```

I have also updated my hosts file with: 127.0.0.1 odyssey.rain.network

Thank you in advance!